# How to check if one or more file/s (directory /ies) exist with Bash?

Tags: directory, ls

In CentOS with Bash 3.2.52(2) I try to create two backup directories after ensuring they did not exist before:

```
rm -rf "${general_backups_dir}"
rm -rf "${specific_backups_dir}"
mkdir -p "${general_backups_dir}"
mkdir -p "${specific_backups_dir}"
```

To test the operation I can `ls -la` and/or work in debug mode but I desire a more precise way to indicate existence of the two directories.

---

This didn't work:

```
ls -la ${HOME} | grep "${general_backups_dir}"
ls -la ${HOME} | grep "${specific_backups_dir}"
```

Let along, I would prefer a single line operation such as (pseudocode):

```
ls -la ${HOME} | grep *EXPRESSION_INCLUDED_IN_BOTH_DIRECTORY_NAMES*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-d` test operator on `bash` to check for the existence of a directory:

```
if [[ -d testdir ]]; then echo "testdir already exists"; else mkdir testdir; fi
```

You can replace 'testdir' with a variable. Double quote the variable for safety:

```
if [[ -d "$backup_dir"]]; then echo "$backup_dir already exists"; else mkdir "$backup_dir"; fi
```

If this is a nested directory (for example, dir1/dir2/dir3), use `mkdir -p` instead.

More details on file test operators in `bash`: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to check whether a file exists in POSIX shells is:

```
if [ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ]; then
  printf '%s\n' "The $file file exists"
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    if [ -L "$file" ]; then
      echo "and it's a symlink to a directory"
    else
      echo "and it's a directory"
    fi
  else
    echo "and it's not a directory (or I couldn't tell if it was)"
  fi
else
  printf '%s\n' "$file does not appear to exist"
fi
```

So, you can insert the code you want to run in the case that matters to you there.

Now note that because of `-f`,

```
rm -rf -- "$file" || exit
```

Will be successful in the case where `$file` didn't exist beforehand. The only case where `rm` returns with a failure exit status is when the file still exists afterwards (it was there but could not be removed).

So you probably don't need to check beforehand unless you want to cover the case where `$file` existed but was not of type *directory*.

And:

```
mkdir -p -- "$file" || exit
```

Will succeed as long as `$file` exists and can be determined to be a directory afterwards even if it's because it already exists.

So again, you probably don't need to do the test beforehand.